# Waiting for a blocking GC ProfileSaver when using big array of data in android renderscript

Tags: android, renderscript

i want to use renderscript for processing some stuff that require rather "big" array of data for each thread executed. i'm still not sure if it's big enough, but using it will trigger "Waiting for a blocking GC ProfileSaver" message in logcat, and blocked the application like... forever. I'm using custom struct defined in rs file like this:

```
typedef struct myStruct {
    int data[65000];
} myStruct_t;
```

and use it in rs kernel, called using forEach function:

```
// in rs file
myStruct_t RS_KERNEL process(myStruct_t aIn, uint32_t x) {
    myStruct_t aOut;
    // do stuff with aIn and save the result in aOut.
    // and finally return aOut
    return aOut;
}
```

```
// in java file
...
RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(this);
Element el = ScriptField_myStruct.createElement(rs);
alloc = Allocation.createSized(rs, el, 10);
retval = Allocation.createTyped(rs, alloc.getType());
process = new ScriptC_process(rs);
...
alloc.copyFromUnchecked(data); // data is array of integer
process.forEach_process(alloc, retval);
```

Basically, i have 650K data (int) to process, and i want to spread that across 10 thread using renderscript. However, when i scale down the array to about 2000, and increase the allocation count to 325 (the total still 650K), the "Waiting for a blocking GC ProfileSaver" still occured, but the app can show the main activity after 13-14s delay (due to GC). i'm pretty sure i don't have memory problem (there is plenty of free memory).

is this too big for a custom Element to have 65K array of data inside it? is there any workaround that i can use?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unclear why you would need a single element as a 64k int array. I would look at single-source renderscript and put the renderscript invocation on its own thread.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with aIn? Normally you would put the data in an allocation of type integer, and process this allocation with a kernel. The variable x would play the role of the index of your data array - with Renderscript you do not manage the number of threads.

Comment: @MorrisonChang because i want to process 65k int array at each rs thread. and called using `forEach` in java side. Is it possible to spread block of 65k int array accross rs therad without using mapping kernel? (like ordinary thread using IDs). I will check the single-source renderscript and see if i can solve it there. Thanks!

Comment: @spectralio it's just normal arithmetic operation (like filter). i can use an Allocation of array of int though, but how can i specify each thread to use like index 0-65k, 65k1-130k, etc. (kind of ordinary thread)?

Comment: Well, the beauty of Renderscript is that you do not need to manually assign index ranges to your threads. When you start a kernel with foreach, Renderscript decides how many threads to start (or it may even use the GPU), and automatically assigns index ranges to these threads. After completion, the kernel function will have been executed for each index of the input allocation, using several threads in parallel. The x variable is the current index position, and you can get other input values (e.g. at neighbouring positions) with rsGetElementAt.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using different approach when allocating. Instead of using custom struct (element) with 65k ints each and then allocating 10 of them (so 65k * 10 = 650k), i'm allocating 650k ints in one shot and using ScriptC' `bind_${var}` to access them in rs kernel.